# Generating random numbers with upper and lower standard deviation of the scatter

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, standard-deviation

I have to produce randomly generated, normally distributed numbers, based on an astronomical table containing a most probable value and a standard deviation. The peculiar thing is that the standard deviation is not given by one, but two numbers - an upper standard deviation of the error and a lower, something like this:

```
mass_object, error_up, error_down
7.33, 0.12, 0.07
9.40, 0.04, 0.02
6.01, 0.11, 0.09
...
```

For example, this means for the first object that if a random mass `m` gets generated with `m<7.33`, then probably it will be further away from `7.33` than in the case that `m>7.33`. So I am looking now for a way to randomly generate the numbers and this way has to include the 2 possible standard deviations. If I was dealing with just one standard deviation per object, I would create the random number (mass) of the first object like that:

```
mass_random = np.random.normal(loc=7.33, scale=0.12)
```

Do you have ideas how to create these random numbers with upper and lower standard deviation of the scatter? Tnx

Comment: If the standard deviations are not symmetric (upper and lower are different), then it's not a normal distribution, but some other distribution. There's a list of scipy's supported Continuous Statistical Distributions here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/continuous.html# You'll want to choose the distribution that best matches the data.

Comment: @SNygard uuh, nice, thanks! I might actually experiment with a few different distributions and see what makes the most sense with the data. Do you have a suggestion, maybe something like a plain vanilla minimal approach for the non-symetric scatter I am having? Or a site with examples? I am looking now for examples, too. Thanks already!

Comment: I'm guessing that your data is similar to normal, but "skewed" higher or lower. Check out this article about asymmetric distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness
If you have enough raw data, you can try fitting distributions to the data, then generate new data from the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, a normal distribution has the same standard deviation in each direction (it's symmetric around the mean). So we know our distribution won't be normal. We can try a lognormal approach, since this allows us to introduce the idea of [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness). To do this in Python, you'll need Scipy. Here's a crude approach, assuming that 68% of data is on the mean, 16% is at the high point, and 16% is at the low point. We fit the distribution to that crude dataset, then we can calculate new points from the distribution:

```py
import scipy.stats

#  Choose one of the rows
mean, high, low = 7.33, 0.12, 0.07

#  Create a dummy dataset to fit the distribution
values = [mean] * 68 + [mean + high] * 16 + [mean - low ] * 16

# Print the fit distribution
fit_dist = scipy.stats.lognorm.fit(values)
print(fit_dist)

#  Calculate 10 new random values based on the fit
scipy.stats.lognorm.rvs(*fit_dist, size=10)

array([7.25541865, 7.34873107, 7.33831589, 7.36387121, 7.26912469,
       7.33084677, 7.35626689, 7.33907124, 7.32522422, 7.31688687])
```

Comment: Did you mean `[high + mean] * 16`?

Comment: Awesome, I I tested your code snippet and it does what I want, so I accepted your answer! Please, implement the suggested correction by Chris

Answer (score 1):

The immediate solution would be a two step sampling: 
for a given row `i`, one samples from a uniform distribution over  the interval `error_down` and `error_up` obtaining `\sigma_i`, and then one samples the final value from a normal distribution with mean `m_i` and standard deviation `\sigma_i`.

In practice, one imports `numpy`, defines a custom function `sampling` and, then, applies it at the whole table:

```
import numpy as np


def sampling (row) :

      sigma = np.random.uniform(row[1],      row[2])
      m = row[0]
      return (np.random.normal(m, sigma)) 
    

sampled_values = map(sampling, table)
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, Paolo, and thanks for the answer! But I am don't understand why I should apply a random uniform sampling. Maybe I don't understand you answer, maybe you didn't understand my question... The value `error_down` indicates what is the spread of all the errors below the mean value, and it is a different value than for the errors above the mean. So I don't have a symmetric spread, as SNygard has written in his answer. Maybe you can clarify why I should use `np.random.uniform`. Anyways, thanks for the answer, I upvote it!